# How many nuclide packages?

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I thought I'd give Nuclide a try and after running `apm install nuclide-installer` I went to the packages tab and searched for "nuclide".

Unfortunately the docs says:

> From there, filter your installed packages by nuclide- and you should
>   see quite a few results!

I see 1 `nuclide-language-hack`, which i'm guessing doesn't equal "quite a few".

Has something gone wrong? How many packages should there be?

Comment: @ssorallen Thanks for adding the extra tag, I don't have enough rep for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nuclide is a single Atom package named ['nuclide'](https://atom.io/packages/nuclide).** Install it with `apm install nuclide`.

Prior to [Nuclide's Unified Package](https://nuclide.io/blog/2016/01/13/Nuclide-v0.111.0-The-Unified-Package/) released on 2016-01-13, Nuclide consisted of 44 separate Atom packages. At the time of my original answer, which is still below, Nuclide was 12 packages.

***Original answer:***

*The list of `nuclide-` packages is at 12 at the moment:*

*https://github.com/facebooknuclideapm/nuclide-installer/blob/master/lib/config.json*

*Since you install `nuclide-installer` itself, that makes a total of 13 `nuclide-` packages you should see after installation. You should be able to watch that file in the near future for a list of Nuclide packages.*

Comment: Since the questions I've tried several things, but on a Windows 2012 R2 server VM I only have 3. An Ubuntu VM has all 13 though.

Comment: From [docs](https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/setup/#windows): `Atom can be installed on Windows. Some features of Nuclide may work on Windows, but the full Nuclide experience is not yet supported.`